# macで長時間のプログラム実行をする際、実行速度が遅くなる

Tags: macos

macで長時間(3時間以上10時間以下程度）を要するプログラム実行をしています。
途中でプログラムが休止されないようにスリープには入らないような設定はしているのですが、実行からしばらく時間が経つとプログラムの実行速度が遅くなっているように思います。
同じような経験がある方はいますでしょうか？
また、もし経験があって解決された方がいましたら、ご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

UNIX系のOSでは、長時間CPUを使用しているプロセスはnice値が上がります。※優先度が下がる
管理者権限が必要ですが、niceコマンドやreniceコマンドでnice値を下げる（優先度が上がる）と問題が改善するかもしれません。
nice値はpsコマンドやtopコマンドで確認することができます。

遅く感じるのはそのプログラムだけでしょうか。システム全体が重く感じるときはメモリ不足でスラッシングが発生していることも考えられます。

プログラム起動直後と数時間後のメモリ使用量やCPU時間(※)のデータがあればもっと的確な回答が得られると思います。
※topコマンドを使うとメモリ使用量、CPU時間、nice値が確認できます。